# Symfony 6 - personalize a checkbox with MyCheckboxType

Tags: symfony

I would like to personalize a checkBox. I create a file MyCheckboxType.php in Form/Type with the code :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MyCheckboxType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        // Les [] equivaut à array()
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'attr' => ['class' => 'cPerso'],
            'label_attr' => ['class'=>'cEtiquette']
        ));
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return CheckboxType::class;
    }
}
```

It works for 'label_attr' but not for 'attr' (
I tested with 'attr', 'row_attr' and 'widget_attr' ... :-) ), the class of the label have changed but not for the class of the input :

[image]

Thank's for your help.

Thank you for your answers

attached the requested code parts which refer to the checkbox :

Twig :

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(my_form.rupture) }}
    {{ form_widget(my_form.rupture, {'attr': {'class':'form-control'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(my_form.rupture) }}
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public function insert(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $produit = new Produit;
    $formProduit = $this->createForm(ProduitType::class,$produit);
    // Ajout d'un groupe d'enregistrement pour cibler la contrainte de validation sur certains formulaire
    // quand on ajoute un groupe de contrainte à un form il faut que toutes les contraintes appartiennent à
    // un groupe et l'associer au form ici on ajoute all pour la contrainte de longueur du nom ( on l'ajoute
    // également à update)
    $formProduit->add('creer', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Insertion d\'un produit',
        'validation_groups'=>array('registration','all')));

    // Récupère les données dans l'entité
    $formProduit->handleRequest($request);

    // Teste l'existence de la méthode Post dans l'objet Request et teste la méthode isValid() qui contrôle
    // que toutes les données du formulaire vérifient les contraintes de validation.
    if($request->isMethod('post') && $formProduit->isValid()){


        $file = $formProduit['lienImage']->getData();

        // Tests le type de valeur retournée, si la valeur est de type string (pas d'image ) il faut rediriger l'action de nouveauvers l'action insert()
        if(!is_string($file)){
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            // Déplace le fichier image
            $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('images_directory'), $filename
            );

            $produit->setLienImage($filename);

        } else {

            //Affiche un message d'erreur si pas d'image choisi, pour cela il faut 2 paramètres
            // - une variable FlashBag : 'message' pour le message d'erreur,
            // - une variable de session 'statut' met en évidence le statut de l'erreur
            // dans le composant 'alert' de Bootstrap
            $session = $request->getSession();
            $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Vous devez choisir une image pour le produit');
            $session->set('statut','danger');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('insert'));
        }
        // Récupère l'Entity Manager pour pouvoir insérer les données dans l'entité
        
        //Si tout se passe bien il faut persister l'objet $produit
        $em->persist($produit);
        // mise à jour de la base de données
        $em->flush();

        // Affiche un message pour confirmer l'insertion d'un produit
        $session=$request->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('message','Un nouveau produit a été ajouté !');
        $session->set('statut','success');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('liste'));

    }

    return $this->render('Admin/create.html.twig',
        array('my_form'=>$formProduit->createView()));
}
```

Entity :

```
class ProduitType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom',TextType::class,array('label' => 'Nom produit :'))
            ->add('prix',NumberType::class,array('label' => 'Prix :'))
            ->add('quantite',NumberType::class,array('label' => 'Quantité :'))
            ->add('rupture',MyCheckboxType::class,array('label' => 'Rupture de stock ?','required'=>false))
            ->add('lienImage',FileType::class,array('label' => 'Image :','required'=>false, 'data_class'=>null,
                'empty_data'=>'aucune image'))
            ->add('reference',ReferenceType::class, array('label'=>'Référence du produit',"required"=>false))
            // IMBRIQUER UN FORMULAIRE DANS UN FORMULAIRE
            // entry_type : précise le nom du formulaire à imbrique
            // allow_add : autorise l'ajout d'autant de formulaires imbriqués
            // allow_delete : autorise la suppression de formulaire imbriqués
            //->add('distributeurs',CollectionType::class, array('entry_type'=>DistributeurType::class, 
            //    'allow_add'=>true,'allow_delete'=>true ));
            ->add('distributeurs', EntityType::class,
                 array ('class' => Distributeur::class,
                        'choice_label'=>'nom',
                        'label'=>'Selection des distributeurs',
                        'multiple'=>true,
                        'required'=>false,
                        ));
    }
      


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Produit::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably overriding your class attribute somewhere in your twig files.

Comment: As @Hast said, you should have something overriding your attribute. Can you add your twig file and your controller part where you create the form ?

Comment: As already mentioned, `setDefaults` only works if the option is not set in another way, but you are passing it to `form_widget`. Also, you _might_ need to merge `attr` with the parent's in `buildView()`.